# Moving and Resizing a Surface Window itself

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I move/resize a `SurfaceWindow` itself by dragging/pinching with my fingers without it having abnormal behavior? I have a Surface Window, with `IsManipulationEnabled` checked. In `ManipulationStarting`, I have:

```
    e.ManipulationContainer = this; <--- source of unpredictable behavior?
    e.Handled = true;
```

In `ManipulationDelta`:

```
    this.Left += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    this.Top += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
    this.Width *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X; <----zooming works properly
    this.Height *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;

    e.Handled = true;
```

The problem with moving is that it will keep jumping around between two totally different position, giving it a flickering effect. I printed out some of the data in the console and it seems that e.ManipulationOrigin keeps changing. The following data is the values after i drag across the screen (only printed X values) and holding my finger down **stationary** at the end for a second:

```
Window.Left    e.Manipulation.Origin.X    e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1184           699.616                    0
1184           577.147                    -122.468
1062           577.147                    0
1062           699.264                    122.117
1184           699.264                    0
1184           576.913                    -122.351

and it goes on
```

You can see from `Window.Left` that it's jumping between 2 position. How do I get it to just stay still after I stop moving the window with my fingers?

Answer (score 0):

The code below at least allows you to drag; It gets around the problem you are having by using screen coordinates - as using window coordinates means the point of reference is changing as the window moves.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/671379/How-to-drag-window-with-finger-not-mouse for more info..

```
 static void MakeDragging(Window window) {
            bool isDown = false;
            Point position = default(Point);
            window.MouseDown += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed) return;
                isDown = true;
                position = window.PointToScreen(eventArgs.GetPosition(window));
            };
            window.MouseUp += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Released) return;
                isDown = false;
            };
            window.MouseMove += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (!isDown) return;
                Point newPosition = window.PointToScreen(eventArgs.GetPosition(window));
                window.Left += newPosition.X - position.X;
                window.Top += newPosition.Y - position.Y;
                position = newPosition;
            };
        } //MakeDragging
```

Comment: I don't think moving with multiple fingers will work properly with this